# how to set value of field by Variable in laravel controller

Tags: laravel

i have this code in store function of controller:

```
public function store(taskRequestStore $request,TaskService $service)
       {
       $request->TaskDate = CalendarUtils::convertNumbers($request->TaskDate, true);
       $request->TaskDate = CalendarUtils::createCarbonFromFormat('Y-m-d', $request->TaskDate)->format('Y-m-d');
             
       $attributes = $request->all(['Caption','TaskDsc','office_id','TaskDate','Type','Priority_id']);
                                
       $office = $service->create($attributes);
       return redirect()->back();
}
```

how to send  $request->TaskDate to 'TaskDate' in $attributes?